Search km radius excluding do not email
I'm looking to search for contacts within a given radius of a postal code (home, billing, or work address) but exclude those marked do not email, no bulk emails, and exclude contact subtype "child". Wondering what others thoughts are on the best way to achieve this?
Should I use the search radius in advanced search, and then export the fields I want to exclude and manually exclude them from my results? Is there an easier way to achieve this?
Thanks

Under Custom Searches you should find an Include Exclude option, so if you create Group A, and Group B, you can then use the Inc/Excl to say 'give me A but not B'

You can do the proximity search and save those contacts to a group, then do your second search, limiting it to members of that group.
